# x^p - 1/x^p inequality?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $p \ge 1$ be an integer and $z \approx 1$ be a real number (e.g. let $.9 \le z \le 1.1$). I would like a bound on the following expression:

$$\frac{\left|z^p - z^{-p}\right|}{z-1}$$

In other words, I want a bound on $z^p - z^{-p}$ that captures a multiplicative dependence on $(z-1)$. For example, I suspect the following but cannot prove it:

$$\left|z^p - z^{-p}\right|\le C|z-1|e^{Cp|z-1|}$$
for some sufficiently large universal constant $C>0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVT gives a much better inequality. For $a \leq z \leq 1.1$ we have $|z^{p}-z^{-p}|=\frac {|z^{2p}-1|} {|z|^{p}} \leq \frac  1 a^{p} (2p)|t^{2p-1}| |z-1|$ where $t$ lies between $z$ and $1$. If $0.9 \leq z \leq 1.1$, for example, you get $|z^{p}-z^{-p}|\leq  \frac  {2p(1.1)^{2p-1}} {(0.9)^{p}} |z-1|$.

Comment: I see, MVT was a great idea, thanks! (The inequality you suggest is actually the same as the one I proposed. If say $z \ge 1$, then $z^{2p-1} \approx e^{Cp(z-1)}$ for some constant $C>0$.)